# What's the therapeutic index of Pethidine (Meperidine in the US)?

Tags: pharmacology, opioid

What's the therapeutic index $\left(\frac{LD_{50}}{ED_{50}}\right)$ of Pethidine (Meperidine in the US) via the intravenous route for humans or whatever species you can find? The therapeutic window $\left(\frac{TD_{50}}{ED_{50}}\right)$ for humans will suffice if accompanied by the therapeutic index for pethidine via IV of another species.

Pethidine is an opioid painkiller with approximately $\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}$ the strength of morphine and a definite influence on monoaminergic neurons.

I imagine it'd be in the neighbourhood of 30-100, like most opioids that have been implemented in medicine.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This seems like an answerable question.

Comment: Tell me about it... It would be nice if those that think I've done a poor job in asking this question could tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: I have not downvoted but perhaps people feel this is a medical question not a biological one. A biologist is unlikely to know the answer, a pharmacist or a surprisingly knowledgeable doctor would.

Comment: Pharmacology is a biologica/biochemical pursuit, not just the purview of medicine or pharmacy.

Comment: If so, where am I supposed to ask this question as far as stackexchange sites? This biology stackexchange is best suited for me to ask this question.

Comment: In any case I created a new tag to suite this question.

Comment: Just go ahead and ask. Remember that anyone can answer on SE, so someone with the answer may come along. Feel free to publicize your questions in other venues. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what those venues are for pharmacology questions.

Comment: Maybe someone was reading your question upside down and thought they were up-voting....

Comment: Sounds about right. I've been trying to get a pharmacy stackexchange site started but that's going to take at least a few months even if it gets a relatively large amount of support.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I reached:

[image]

Source: Page 105, The Complete Recovery, By Anthea Hatfield [Google Book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HlGwAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]